# Parsing, editing and saving dhcpd.conf file with Python 3.6

Tags: file, python-3.6, config, edit, dhcp

I want to edit/create or delete a part of area of my dhcpd.conf file settled in Raspberry Pi.

I want to edit file located at /etc/dhcpcd.conf and if it contains static ip config block, I will update this block, otherwise I want to create this block and I also want to remove this block in some cases without damaging any other part of the file. Therefore, I have to write a function doing that operations in config file. I saw ConfigParser package for that but I could not sure to use it. How can I solve this problem?

I use this kind of solution but it is not reliable and not working. Maybe using ConfigParse will be more clean solution than that.

```sh
interface eth0
static ip_address=192.168.0.4/24
static routers=192.168.0.1
static domain_name_servers=192.168.0.1
```

```py
@staticmethod
    def change_static_ip(ip_address, routers, dns):
        conf_file = '/etc/dhcpcd.conf'
        try:            
            vars = ['interface', 'static ip_address', 'static routers', 'static domain_name_servers']
            new_values = ['eth0', ip_address, routers, dns]
            changes = dict(zip(vars,new_values))

            RE = '(('+'|'.join(changes.keys())+')\s*=)[^\r\n]*?(\r?\n|\r)'
            pat = re.compile(RE)

            def jojo(mat,dic = changes):
                return dic[mat.group(2)].join(mat.group(1,3))

            with open(conf_file,'rb') as f:
                content = f.read().decode('utf-8')

            with open(conf_file,'wb') as f:
                f.write(pat.sub(jojo,content))
        except Exception as ex:
            logging.exception("IP changing error: %s", ex)
        finally:
            pass
```

Answer (score 3):

I found your question while searching for the same solution as well, so I decided to try it out myself.

Based off of your example, I will show what I similarly did:

```
    @staticmethod
    def change_static_ip(ip_address, routers, dns):
        conf_file = '/etc/dhcpcd.conf'
        try:            
            # Sanitize/validate params above
            with open(conf_file, 'r') as file:
                data = file.readlines()

            # Find if config exists
            ethFound = next((x for x in data if 'interface eth0' in x), None)

            if ethFound:
                ethIndex = data.index(ethFound)
                if data[ethIndex].startswith('#'):
                    data[ethIndex].replace('#', '') # commented out by default, make active

            # If config is found, use index to edit the lines you need ( the next 3)
            if ethIndex:
                data[ethIndex+1] = f'static ip_address={ip_address}/24'
                data[ethIndex+2] = f'static routers={routers}'
                data[ethIndex+3] = f'static domain_name_servers={dns}'

            with open(conf_file, 'w') as file:
                file.writelines( data )

        except Exception as ex:
            logging.exception("IP changing error: %s", ex)
        finally:
            pass
```

If you need to pass an argument to remove static config for eth0, add '#' to first like like so:

```
    '#interface eth0'
```

Answer (score 2):

Just a short edit for [Blake's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61599542/7635995):

```
data[ethIndex] = data[ethIndex].replace('#', '')
```

should be used in python3 because

```
data[ethIndex].replace('#', '')
```

doesn't make change by itself